# Check for null value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

```
 var entries = from video in Video.GetTopVideos().AsEnumerable()
                      select
                      new XElement("item",
                          new XElement("title", video.Title),
                          new XElement("category", video.Tags[video.Tags.Count-1].Name),
                          //...........
```

If the property video.Tags==null then an exception throws. 
Can I check for null value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
var entries = from video in Video.GetTopVideos().AsEnumerable()
                      where video.Tags != null
                      select
                      new XElement("item",
                          new XElement("title", video.Title),
                          new XElement("category", video.Tags[video.Tags.Count-1].Name),
                          //...........
```

Or, if you want to make sure that you always have something even if the `Tags` property is `null`:

```
var entries = from video in Video.GetTopVideos().AsEnumerable()
   let cat = (video.Tags != null && video.Tags.Count > 0) ? video.Tags[video.Tags.Count-1].Name : "**No Category**
   select
   new XElement("item",
       new XElement("title", video.Title),
       new XElement("category", cat),
       //...........
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You can rewrite that line as

```
video.Tags != null ? new XElement(...) : null
```

If `Tags` is null, no `XElement` will be emitted for `category` in your resulting XML. You could, of course, elect to provide another default element instead of null, if you wish.

Comment: Also need to make sure that `video.Tags.Count > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Add a where clause that states:

where video.Tags != null

This will limit your results to only those that do have Tags.

Your query will ultimately look like the following:

```
var entries = from video in Video.GetTopVideos().AsEnumerable()
              where video.Tags != null
              select  new XElement("item",
                      new XElement("title", video.Title),
                      new XElement("category", video.Tags[video.Tags.Count-1].Name),
                      //...........
```

Comment: Or if you need the element created anyway then video.Tags == null ? String.Empty : video.Tags[video.Tags.Count-1].Name